# Select all values drop list excel

Tags: excel-2013

Can anyone tell me if there is any shortcut to select all the possible columns in the subtotal menu? I have a lot of data and doesn´t seem very efficient to hand click each column...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For selecting all the available data in one go under one column you can do:

```
ctrl + shift + down key
```